# What is "50 Reputation?" Explain please

Tags: discussion

I wanted to make a comment about tithing. Didn't understand how to. Please explain "50 Reputation." Anyway, here's my comment: "The modern practice of church tithing is not supported by the teachings of scripture.  Church tithing began in the late nineteenth century when a Wesleyan Church in Cincinnati hosted multiple fund-raising events to erase its enormous debt.  Fledgling on the brink of bankruptcy and devoid of options, a layman came up with the idea of, “storehouse tithing.”  It was an instant success and soon the news spread like wildfire throughout Christendom and the practice of storehouse tithing caught on.  At the time, it seemed the answer to the debts and financial woes of churches whose church members gave indiscriminately." http://www.bibleanswerstand.org/QA_tithe.htm

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please have a read of the [Tour] - it explains what reputation points are and why you can't immediately comment on other people's questions.

Comment: What is your question about tithing?  Are you actually looking for information on the history of tithing?  Please edit your "question" to make it clear what you would like to know.  Meanwhile, you may find an answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/66618/did-everyone-tithe-in-israel-when-did-the-tithing-come-into-the-church

Comment: @curiousdannii - The [tour] doesn't really say much about reputation points.  It is best to go to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation